# Passing all datas to the URL isn't the way to go, I think

Tags: node.js, angular

I recently started to use NodeJS into my Angular program, so far, I'm doing it like this :

node :

```
app.get('/register/:username/:password', function(req, res){
    db.collection('users').insertOne({
        username: req.params.username,
        password: req.params.password,
        nbVotes: 0,
        avatar: `https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=${req.params.username}`,
        grade: 'Membre'        
    }, function(err, data){
        res.json(data)
    })
})
```

Angular :

```
  this.http.get('http://localhost:3001/register/'+ username+ '/'+ password).subscribe((data: any) => {
  sessionStorage.setItem('name', username);
  sessionStorage.setItem('password', password);
  window.location.href = '/profil/' + username;
  console.log("Connected ! ")
```

There is probably ( definitely ) a better way to do this, right ? Because going by the url like this feels... off. What if they were 50 inputs to check ?

Comment: You're absolutely right, there are a bunch of better ways to do this :) . I might suggest a read at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods and https://nodejs.dev/learn/get-http-request-body-data-using-nodejs

Comment: It looks good and doable, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

From your code provided I could see that, you are passing the input values username and password as params in the URL, which is a bad practice since the password which is a secret entity will be visible in the URL and must be only passed through the body. Since the request is for registering the user, You must use the POST request instead of the GET request. And I suggest you to use some type of encryption methods like crypto while handling password.

Comment: Yes, that's what the whole post is about 
I was just wondering how to use in the body